# Oozie/Hadoop: How do I define an input dataset when it's more complex than just a static file?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I'm trying to run an existing Hadoop job using Oozie (I'm migrating from AWS).

In AWS Mapreduce I programmatically submit jobs, so before the job is submitted, my code programmatically find the input.

My input happens to be the last SUCCESSFUL run of another job. To find the last SUCCESSFUL run I need to scan an HDFS folder, sort by the timestamp embedded in the folder naming convention, and find the most recent folder with an _SUCCESS file in it.

How to do this is beyond my oozie-newbie comprehension.

Can someone simply describe for me what I need to configure in Oozie so I have some idea of what I'm attempting to reach for here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to the following configuration for oozie: https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example/blob/master/oozie-workflows/coord-app.xml

There is a tag called "done-flag" there you can put the _SUCCESS file in order to trigger a workflow or for your case a map reduce job. There are also parameter for scheduling the job

${coord:current(1 + (coord:tzOffset() / 60))}
  ....